# Ansible var jinja2 template

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I've been trying to reference a variable in Ansible but each time I receive an error.

yaml var file has:

```
nodes:
  barni:
    - { name: 'LoginGraceTime', value: '2m'}
    - { name: 'MaxSessions', value: '6'}
    - { name: 'ChallengeResponseAuthentication', value: 'yes'}
```

where barni is the "hostname -s". I need something dynamic in the sshd_config.j2 template to match the hostname in the variable. Template works fine if I specify node.barni.sshdextra but what I need is for 'barni' to be replaced dynamically with the short name of the server name.

```
{% for item in node.barni.sshdextra %}
{{ item.name }} {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

In tasks I can reference the short hostname using 
`hostname_mounts: "{{hostname_shortname.replace('-','')}`
`hostname_shortname: "{{inventory_hostname.split('.')[0]}}` in the variable def file

```
- name: nfs - edit - remove nfs lines from /etc/fstab
  command: sed -i '/nfs/d' /etc/fstab
  ignore_errors: yes
  when: "'{{inventory_hostname}}'.startswith('{{hostname_mounts}}')"
  tags: [ nfs ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's make sure you understand the concept of Ansibles `host_vars`.

If you have a file `host_vars/barni.yml` (though the full name not the shortname is used) with the contents:

```
nodes:
  - { name: 'LoginGraceTime', value: '2m'}
  - { name: 'MaxSessions', value: '6'}
  - { name: 'ChallengeResponseAuthentication', value: 'yes'}
```

...you simply could loop over the `nodes` then. `host_vars` and `group_vars` usually are used to solve this kind of situation where you have different configuration for different hosts or sets of host.

But I agree there are situations where this is uncomfortable - and to finally answer your question: You can use the variable `inventory_hostname_short` to get the shortname of the host:

```
{% for item in node[inventory_hostname_short].sshdextra %}
{{ item.name }} {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I took your idea about loops to the next level and I was able to resolve this issue by using in a template file:

`    # node specific settings
    {% if nodes is defined and nodes != [] %}
    {% for nodename, val in nodes.iteritems() %}
{% if nodename == hostname_shortname %}
# node.{{ nodename }}.sshdextra options: 
{% for option, defs in val.iteritems() %}
{% if option == 'sshdextra' %}
{% for item in defs %}
{{ item.name }} {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}    `

Thank you !!